# Package for the Closest Vector Problem (CVP)?

Tags: algorithms, lattices, mathematical-software

Let $A$ be a positive definite, real $n \times n$ matrix. This defines a norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$. Now I have a given point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and I want to find the lattice point $x \in \mathbb{Z}^n$ that is closest to $p$ with respect to this norm. This is commonly known as the **Closest Vector Problem** (CVP) and seems to be very important. So I guess algorithms to solve this should be implemented somewhere. However, I was not able to find something.

Is this there a package for solving this problem for some common mathematical software like Maple, Mathematica, Sage, etc?

Note that I am not interested in some approximation using LLL or so, I want really the (or one) closest vector!

Comment: I believe this eventually boils down to checking all lattice vectors within a certain box around zero, depending on $A$. If you do that smartly (see http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777278-8/home.html) you might save some time, but depending on your application a rougher (=larger) box doesn't matter. Or your dimension is so large that you cannot solve it anyways...

Comment: Am I missing something or is your reference about the shortest vector problem rather than the closest vector problem (I think the former is only a spectal case of the latter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`fplll` (available here: https://github.com/fplll/fplll), a C++ implementation of a selection of lattice algorithms, has a CVP solver:

> It also includes a floating-point implementation of the Kannan-Fincke-Pohst algorithm [K83,FP85] that finds a shortest non-zero lattice vector. For the same task, the GaussSieve algorithm [MV10] is also available in fplll. Finally, it contains a variant of the enumeration algorithm that computes a lattice vector closest to a given vector belonging to the real span of the lattice.

Magma has a CVP solver. Details here: https://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/overview/2/17/9/

> Magma includes a highly optimized algorithm for enumerating all short vectors in a lattice with given norm. This algorithm, developed by Damien Stehlë, is used for computing the minimum, the shortest vectors, short vectors in a given range, and vectors close to or closest to a given vector (possibly) outside the lattice.

Answer (score 4):

Victor Shoup's NTL package has an implementation of LLL-BKZ. The "B" in the name stands for "block". If you set the block size equal to the dimension of the lattice, then it should return a list of short basis vectors, with the smallest vector in the basis being a solution to SVP. I guess for CVP you can try to set up your CVP as an SVP in one higher dimension.

Comment: Basic question: how can CVP be expressed as an SVP in one higher dimension?

Comment: @ElliotGorokhovsky Let $A$ be an $n$-by-$n$ matrix whose rows are the given basis for $L$, and let $\boldsymbol{v}$. Form a new matrix $B$ whose upper right is $A$, whose last column is $0,0,\ldots,0,c$, and whose last row is $(\boldsymbol{v},c)$.  Then one adjust $c$, depending on the length of $\boldsymbol{v}$ and the discriminant of $A$, so that a small vector in $B$ is likely to consist of a linear combination of its first $n$ rows together with exactly $\pm1$ copy of its bottom row.  And that expresses $\boldsymbol v$ as a lattice vector plus a small error, so approximately solves CVP.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Could you explain a bit more how a $c$ with the desired property could be chosen? (Or at least why such a $c$ should exist?)

Answer (score 4):

Sage provides function `closest_vector()` in the module [free_module_integer](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/modules/sage/modules/free_module_integer.html).

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica has [LatticeReduce](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LatticeReduce.html), an implementation of a variant of the LLL algorithm.

Victor Shoup's [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) has a [C++ implementation](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/doc/LLL.cpp.html) of the LLL algorithm.

Babai's approximation algorithm for CVP, the [nearest plane algorithm](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/ln/cvp.pdf), uses the LLL algorithm. Take a look at Regev's [lecture notes](http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~regev/teaching/lattices_fall_2009/). You may also want to take a look at Peikert's [lecture notes](http://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/lic13/).

Also, take a look at Peikert's comments on [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18425/35925) on the [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I think MAGMA also has a CVP implementation, and `fplll`, despite its name, also does.

Comment: Are you sure that these do what they should? I thought that the LLL algorithm just gives a close vector (which is close enough for many applications) but not necessarily the closest one?

Comment: Yoav, is fplll a command in magma or where?

Comment: I am totally aware of the fact that this is a hard problem. I'm not hoping for short running time, but it should be possible to compute it in reasonable time for small $n$ and I am looking for implementations of this.

Answer (score 3):

It can be formulated as an integer quadratic programming problem, for which you can use e.g. Cplex.

Of course, running time for this approach is likely to be exponential in $n$, but in practice it should be considerably better than exhaustive search in a box.