# For a nilpotent matrix A, are the cardinalities of sets: 1) B: commute with A, 2) B: anticommute with A, 3) B: q-commute with A — the same?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, matrices, nilpotent-matrices

Let us work over finite fields $F_{p^k}$.  Simulations seems to indicate:

**Question 1:** Consider a nilpotent matrix $A$, consider the set of all matrices $B$, such that $AB-qBA=0$, then cardinality of that set does not depend on $q\in F: q\ne 0$, is it true?
So in particular for $A$ being a nilpotent, commute with $A$ and anticommute with $A$ — both have the same cardinality.

(Later edit: proved positively by Darij Grinberg).

**Remarks:** simulations show that the sets themselves depend on $q$ — only cardinalities are the same. Claim above is obviously not true without $A$ being nilpotent e.g. for $A=\operatorname{Id}$ everything commutes with $A$, but nothing non-zero anticommutes (except $\operatorname{char}(F)=2$).

**Question 2:** All the same as above seems to be true when $B$ restricted to be nilpotent, is it true?
I.e. cardinalities of sets $$N_{q,A} = \{B: \text{$B$ nilpotent}, AB-qBA=0 \}$$  do not depend on $q\ne 0$ (for fixed $A$).  Is it true?

Moreover if we stratify nilpotent cone by $B^k=0$, the same seems to be true for each strata:
**Question 3:**  I.e.
$$N_{q,A,k} = \{ B: B^k=0 , AB-qBA=0 \}$$  the cardinality of these sets do not depend on $q\ne 0$ (for fixed $A$). Is it true?

Remark: in earlier version it was claimed that the sets themselves do not depend on $q$ for $k=2$ - but it is not true. ( As Darij Grinberg observed by argument and I rechecked simulation result - already for p=3, n=4 it is not true).

---

Link to Python simulations: https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/count-x-nilp-x-c-x-nilp-0

The case p=3, n=4 is considered in version 6 of the notebook,
the table with results is just above the linked position:
https://www.kaggle.com/alexandervc/count-x-nilp-x-c-x-nilp-0?scriptVersionId=75993799&cellId=10

Comment: The matrix $qA$ is similar to $A$ whenever $A$ is nilpotent and $q \neq 0$. (Indeed, this follows from the Jordan normal form, since each nilpotent Jordan block is similar to its own $q$-multiple.) Thus, $qA = CAC^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix $C$. Now, there is a bijection between the matrices $B$ satisfying $AB = qBA$ and the matrices $B$ satisfying $AB = BA$; namely, this bijection sends a matrix $B$ of the former type to $CB$. This answers Question 1. Not sure about Question 2.

Comment: Pretty sure Question 3 cannot have a positive answer. If the sets are equal, then in particular any matrix $B$ satisfying $AB = BA$ and $B^2 = 0$ must satisfy $AB = 2BA$ and therefore $AB = 0$. But it is easy to find a situation where this is violated (e.g., a quotient algebra $\mathbb{F}_3\left[a,b\right]/\left(a^3, b^2\right)$ in its regular representation as matrices). Of course, this doesn't preclude the possibility that the cardinalities might again be equal.

Comment: The equality of sizes in Question 3 seems to hold even for $q = 0$.

Comment: Actually, the equality of sizes in Question 1 seems to hold for $q = 0$ as well, though this would be far from obvious.

Comment: Ah no, the equality of sizes in Question 1 fails for $q = 0$ when $A = \begin{pmatrix} 0&1&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $F = \mathbb{F}_2$. And the same counterexample works for Question 3. So $q = 0$ is not an option.

Comment: Concerning question 2 - may be among all "C" one can find one that will preserve nilpotent cone ? What do you think ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg very nice argument ! Thank you!

Comment: @darijgrinberg You are right about the question 3 - it seems the set itself depends on "q" - simulation also says that for p=3, n=4 - and A = niltpotent of type 3+1  - I just was blinded looking on my own table . Thanks again !